# Docker: basic example dockerfile to run html file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there any very basic and still viable example for docker and dockerfile to run single html file and show it to the somebody else with the help of docker?

Answer (score 6):

To server a html file on http you will need a web server, so to do this all you need to do is get an docker image of httpd server, put your html file in the root directory of the webserver and expose the service on some port(suppose 8080), Let's do it one by one.

1.) Create a docker file with this content

```
FROM httpd:2.4

COPY ./public-html/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

2.)

```
docker build -t my-apache2 .
```

3.)

```
docker run -dit -p 8080:80 --name my-running-app my-apache2
```

That's it. Your html page should be now available at
http://yourip:8080/public-html