# Serve static HTML files in Apache

Tags: html, docker, apache

I have documentation for an application that consists of a number of static HTML files.

I created a Docker image to serve these files which works, but it has a few issues.

- The "default" web page is `default.html`, rather than `index.html`.  How do I make `default.html` the "default" web page?
- The name of the linked files in a given HTML has a difference case than the file itself.  For example, the link is `viewlist.html` while the file's actual name is `ViewList.html`.  Is there a way to ignore case?
- It might be helpful just to list the files' names.  Is there a way to enable directory listing?

Reference:

- [Docker: basic example dockerfile to run html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970511/docker-basic-example-dockerfile-to-run-html-file#46970703)

Comment: Have you searched in the [Apache Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/)? Also, for server configuration questions, this is the wrong network I’m afraid. Try to head over to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions are not related with the dockerfile, but with the **apache configuration** instead.

Apache configuration file `httpd.conf` might be usually found in `/etc/httpd` or in `/etc/apache/sites-available` or in similar paths, check the documentation of your Apache version.

**Then,**

---

to change your **default index** file to be `index.html`, you need to configure

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

---

to get a **directory listing** when no index file is found; you use, inside a `<Directory>`tag,

```
Options +Indexes
```

---

and, finally, for apache serving files in a **case-insensitive** way, you need to hack the system some way. Linux is case-sensitive file system. So,

you **either** change all your file names to be **lowercase** and  **rewrite** all urls to be lowercase

```
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ${tolower:$1}
```

**or** mount your directory into a case-insensitive **samba** filesystem.

Supose you are serving `opt/www`; you make a SMB share for localhost only, then mount the Samba share to `/shared/www`, and reconfigure apache to use the new mounted samba share. All files in `opt/www` will be mirrored as case-insentitive in `shared/www`